# How to open an excel workbook which has a changing name using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I get reports everyday and need to create another report from it

files I get are "XYZ (current date)" in .xlsx format

I have automated the processes but unable to apply it to everyday files with a click of a button

```
Sub Run_All_Macros()
'Order in which macros will run


'Creatin sheets
add_rename_sheets

'Copying data
copy_data

'Uniques
uniques_sheet

'Connect
connect_sheet

'SNS
SNS_sheet

'Formatting
formatting_sns

End Sub
```

I have made above macros which run perfectly but only in current file.
I want to open "XYZ (current date).xlsx" and run above macros in it

first macro code

```
Sub add_rename_sheets()


Sheets.Add after:=Sheets("East"), Count:=6

Sheets(2).Name = "SNS"
Sheets(3).Name = "Connect"
Sheets(4).Name = "Map"
Sheets(5).Name = "Vl_formula"
Sheets(6).Name = "Uniques"
Sheets(7).Name = "Sourcing Matrix"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop all files on directory like below

```
Sub test()
    Dim file As String, path As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    path = "some path" ' your directory
    
    file = Dir(path & "\" & "*.xlsx")
    Do While file <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(path & "\" & file)
        '   do your code
        '<>
        
        ' </>
        wb.Close
        Set wb = Nothing
        file=dir()
    Loop
    
End Sub
```